# How to upload S3 metadata with a file in Fog?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, fog

I have tried:

```
my_directory.files.create(key: key, body: body,
  metadata: { custom: "x" })
```

And:

```
my_directory.files.create(key: key, body: body,
  custom: "x" })
```

But the "custom" metadata is not showing up in the S3 web interface.

What am I doing it wrong? How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Programming Amazon Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596515812.do) by James Murty (O'Reilly), page 74:

> S3 does not allow you to set arbitrary metadata items to be returned as HTTP headers; only some header names are recognized as legal HTTP headers. Any header with a name the service does not recognize is discarded.

According to the properties panel of [the Amazon S3 console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home), only these metadata fields are allowed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Disposition
- Content-Type
- Content-Language
- Expires
- Content-Encoding
- x-amz-meta-

So, if you want to use custom metadata, make sure you use a key name that starts with `x-amz-meta-`. That would be `x-amz-meta-custom` for example above.