# Can you upload S3 metadata (Specifically "Content-Language") with a file?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Are we able to set the "Content-Language" metadata value for a file which is added to S3?

I'm seeing conflicting answers to this (i.e. [How to upload S3 metadata with a file in Fog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290819/how-to-upload-s3-metadata-with-a-file-in-fog/12293263#12293263) - states that it should be able to be done).

My attempts so far have resulted in the Key being prepended with "x-amz-meta-", so the key ends up being "x-amz-meta-Content-Language" instead of just "Content-Language".

I'm using the AWSSDK for C#:

Below is a snippet of the code (very basic just as an example):

```
var request = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = _bucket,
            Key = filekey,
            InputStream = stream,
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
        };

        //Add metaData collection to request
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> currentMetaData in metaData)
        {
            request.Metadata.Add(currentMetaData.Key, currentMetaData.Value);
            //WHERE Key = "Content-Language" and Value = "en" (or es, it etc)
        }

        using (var client = GetS3Client())
        {
            //WHERE GetS3Client() returns an instance of Amazon.S3.IAmazonS3
            client.PutObject(request);
        }
```

Comment: Consider using `response-content-language` as the header [key](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/AWSSDK_DotNet35/Amazon.S3/Model/ResponseHeaderOverrides.cs#L36) iso `content-language`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we are accessing the files via URL and not using the SDK.
Also, putting "response-content-language" yields "x-amz-meta-response-content-language" as the key.